# How to fetch a file from tarball resides remotely

Tags: python, svn

I wanted to fetch a file from tarball that resides on svn repo.I do have ssh access to svn repo server with particular username and password and wanted to do the same through Python code.

I Don't want to bring the whole tarball to my machine and then extract the required file.

Can anyone tell me how the same can be achieved?

Comment: You could do that with a single `svn` command. Is it important to do with Python?

Comment: Yes @janos it should come from python ,I wanted to integrate it in my yocto recipe file.

Comment: Do you use a python library for running `svn` commands? If yes which one? Or are you simply calling `svn` using `subprocess` or something?

Comment: We are calling svn using subprocess ,In yocto framework we don't really looks for inside implemention ,we simply run our recipe file which internally call some fetcher(implemented in python) to fetch files from svn repo .I just wanted to override these fetcher from mine one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the tarball contents using this `svn` command:

```
svn cat url_to_repo/path/to/tarball
```

You can call this Python using `subprocess`. This `svn` command writes the contents of the file to standard output, so you can read it from `subprocess.PIPE` and unzip it in memory or to a local file.

Here's a sample Python code to get the contents of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

svn_with_args = ['svn', 'cat', 'url_to_repo/path/to/tarball']
proc = subprocess.Popen(svn_with_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
content = ''.join(proc.stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: Thanks janos for your answer .Would you please provide bit more detail in your answer as I am very less familiar with python.Could you shape out the python code here.

Comment: That should be `svn cat url_to_repo/path/to/tarball | tar -xf - -O path/of/filename/inside/tarball >/path/to/file/to/save`, and no, @RajanPathak, StackOverflow is not for doing your homework so please don't ask for complete solutions. Instead, [*try*](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) to come up with your own solution and when it fails, post (another) question to deal with *that specific problem.*

Comment: fine @kostix ,will try out and see how it goes.

Comment: @RajanPathak I added a sample to read the output from `svn cat`. And this is as far as I'm willing to go with this. Kostix is right.

Comment: No problem @janos,You have told me quite a lot and now its my turn to work it out.Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck! When you have enough rep, I'll appreciate if you'll come back and upvote ;-)